# Is it possible to suppress INFO logging output in python?

Tags: python, warnings

I would like to suppress specific INFO output:

```py
INFO     Using categorical units to plot a list of strings that are all parsable as floats or dates. If these strings should be plotted as numbers, cast to the appropriate data type before plotting.
```

I know that warnings can be suppressed, see [warnings — Warning control](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html), but it does not seem to be applicable. The question is general and should not depend on the context, in that case messing up with `matplotlib`
and can avoid it by using another way.

Comment: Yes, you should configure your logger to a log level higher than INFO, e.g. WARNING or ERROR. *How* you do that depends on the logging framework, the logger setup, etc.

Comment: Yes, full solution found [here](https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/why-am-i-getting-this-matplotlib-error-for-plotting-a-categorical-variable/21758) in the case of matplotlib.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. I used logging in my own terms and set it to DEBUG for development reasons.

I also used matplotlib and it just took my debug level definition and I started to see a whole lot of debug messages which were not mine.

My best guess would be to import logging and setting the log level higher than info.

Comment: Do you mean like this: `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)`? It did not work, but I do not understand the `logging` package in detail.

Comment: Yes. But setting it to DEBUG is a higher logging level. You have to set it lower than INFO, like WARNING or ERROR. This makes the filter more restrictive. Then it should be fine.

Comment: This worked: logging.basicConfig(level="INFO")

mlogger = logging.getLogger("matplotlib")
mlogger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

Comment: Solution found [here](https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/why-am-i-getting-this-matplotlib-error-for-plotting-a-categorical-variable/21758).

Comment: Did you try just setting the basic logging level to "WARNING"? I'm certain this would work aswell.

Comment: Did not work for me without the matplotlib specification.